# The head of State of the UK doesn't need a passport to travel, in theory. But what is the reality?

Tags: united-kingdom, royal-family

Because the head of state who is the issuing authority passport so he or she won't need a passport to travel, in theory. However, what is the procedure in reality. Do they still require a diplomatic pass as with all other UK officials? What are the arrangements made?

Comment: A diplomatic passport is still a passport, so, no, the monarch does not have one of those either.  The procedure in reality will depend on the administrative requirements of the country being visited.  US law says that heads of state need an A-1 visa, and it provides a form to stick the visa onto for cases where, as with the UK's monarch, the head of state does not have a passport.  I imagine that other countries just waive passport and visa requirements entirely, and that this may be done more or less formally in different cases.